# Cannot create hotspot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hot-spot

When I create a hotspot, the window shows it to have been created but none of my mobile devices can 'see' this network. Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Hotspot wifi key to `WEP` or remove the security altogether and then see if your devices can connect.

Comment: How do  I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android then this will help you; http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-laptop-android/